# What is REALLY inside that field?

Tags: mysql, datetime

In MYSQL I have a '0' inserted into a DATETIME field called DT. 
making it a "0000-00-00 00:00:00".
I need to compare DT to NOW() and tell if the result is in the past or not.

Some dates have real values, and some dates have a '0' (as said get the "0000-00-00 00:00:00").
How can I check that column DT + INTERVAL 3 MONTH < NOW() ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just want to ignore the `0` dates, so you can simply filter out the `0` dates in your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE DT != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  AND DATE_ADD(DT, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) < NOW()
```

Here's the optimized version of that query. You should try to put your functions on the right side of the criteria so that MySQL can utilize indexes:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE DT != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  AND DT < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that any sql query result, containing NOW() cannot be cached in query cache. Better to use some real datetime value, passed from the script.

Comment: @FractalizeR, thanks for the input. Would we really want queries with NOW() cached because it's only NOW() for a second?

Comment: well, that depends on how busy your website is. You can round NOW() in your script to the nearest 5 mins for example to benefit from query caching in MySQL. But you have an option to implement this in the script logic. Anyway, that was just a notice, not a criticism.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATE_ADD()` function to get what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE_ADD(`DT`, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) < NOW();
```

This will return all columns where (DT + INTERVAL 3 MONTH) < NOW()

Comment: @Ted Try selecting `NOW()` so you can the difference between the two.

Comment: could you specify the query please, I am not sure of what you mean

Comment: `SELECT NOW();` is the entire query

Comment: This gives the current date and time, how can I see the actual value that I have. It is not NULL I know. tested with coalesce

Comment: To see the value you have in your columns you have to select them. `SELECT DT from mytable;`

Comment: I thought that I only get 0000-00-00 00:00:00 displayed, but that the actual value inside may be different, like NULL, '0' or ''. I thought there might have been a way to reveal the real value.